# What is the correct approach to construct NSParagraphStyle during custom text drawing?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The following is the code I use to perform custom text drawing in `UICollectionViewCell`.

```
//
// UICollectionViewCell
//
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    ...
    
    NSParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];

    ...
    
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                titleFont, NSFontAttributeName,
                                textColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                style, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                nil];
    
    [string drawWithRect:centeredTextRect options:options attributes:attributes context:nil];

    ...

    NSDictionary *subtitleAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        subtitleFont, NSFontAttributeName,
                                        textColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                        style, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                        nil];

    [self.subtitle drawWithRect:subtitleCenteredTextRect options:options attributes:subtitleAttributes context:nil];
}
```

I am not confident on the following line although it seems to work

```
NSParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
```

Should it be

```
NSParagraphStyle *style = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle;
```

or

```
NSParagraphStyle *style = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle.mutableCopy;
```

or

I should just make `style` as member variable, so that I just need to construct `NSParagraphStyle` for 1 time and use it multiple times in `drawRect`? (But, is it safe to place NSParagraphStyle as member varialble, since NSParagraphStyle is a mutable item?)

Comment: If you are not going to set any paragraph style properties, why are you making a paragraph style at all? Just delete `style` entirely.

Comment: `since NSParagraphStyle is a mutable item` - `NSParagraphStyle` is immutable, did you mean `NSMutableParagraphStyle`? Anyway, if nobody else mutates your instance, why shouldn't it be safe to store and reuse it? What are your concerns here?

Answer (score 0):

> Should it be
>
> ```objc
> NSParagraphStyle *style = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle;
> ```

This code doesn't make much sense to me. [`defaultParagraphStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsparagraphstyle/1532681-defaultparagraphstyle?language=objc) property defined in the `NSParagraphStyle` class and is not (publicly) overriden in `NSMutableParagraphStyle` interface. Moreover, a developer comment to this property in the `NSParagraphStyle` interface says it's a shared instance:

> This class property returns a shared and cached `NSParagraphStyle` instance with the default style settings, with same value as the result of `[[NSParagraphStyle alloc] init]`.

Thus I would expect that `NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle` instance is not just equal, but it's exactly the same instance which is returned from `NSParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle`:

```objc
NSParagraphStyle *style = NSParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle;
NSMutableParagraphStyle *mutableStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle;
// style and mutableStyle instance refer to the same address
mutableStyle.lineSpacing = 20; // unrecognized selector runtime error
```

---

> or
>
> ```objc
> NSParagraphStyle *style = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle.mutableCopy;
> ```

The problem here is that use of `defaultParagraphStyle` is just redundant when you need an instance of `NSMutableParagraphStyle`. Why referring to an immutable instance when you need a mutable one? Just instantiate it directly.

---

> ```objc
> NSParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
> ```

It's not clear why you initialise a pointer to an immutable object with a mutable object. If you plan to cast it later on to change the data, then it's not really consistent. I suggest making a `NSMutableParagraphStyle` variable and work with it as designed.

---

For the part whether it should be an instance variable/property of your class (instead of local variable), I see nothing wrong with it as long as:

1. Your code is single-threaded
2. You don't pass your `NSMutableParagraphStyle *` instance variable to other instances to store.

For the point no. 2, I mean code like this:

```objc
NSMutableParagraphStyle *mutableStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"MyString" attributes:@{
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: mutableStyle
}];
```

`attrString` is an instance of an immutable class `NSAttributedString`, however it consumes `mutableStyle` here, which can easily be changed at any point after this code.

I'm sure `NSAttributedString` implementation actually takes care of such scenario and makes an immutable copy of the attributes in the dictionary passed, but since you implement your own class which potentially can store an instance of `NSParagraphStyle *` you should be aware that you better store a copy of such an instance if you design a way to initialise it with a value from outside of the class (via a property or constructor).

In case the property is of `NSMutableParagraphStyle` type, it's not that obscure problem (the immutable version is the superclass, thus cannot be used without a compiler warning), but I would still make a copy to avoid unexpected mutations.

---

**TLDR**: initialise the instance with:

```objc
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
```

or store it with a property with copy or/and readonly attributes:

```objc
@property(copy, readonly, nonatomic) NSMutableParagraphStyle *style;
```